# SQL SERVER, DATENAME Cambiar el lenguaje del mes a Catalan

Tags: sql-server

Intento cambiar el lenguaje para que el numero de mes me lo de en catalán con `DATENAME` y `SET LANGUAGE` pero parece que el catalán no lo soporta.

```
SET LANGUAGE Catalan;
SELECT DATENAME(Month, MIFECHA) As Mes;
```

Comment: cámbialo por Spanish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente, el catalán no es un idioma soportado por SQL Server. Los únicos idiomas soportados están almacenados en la vista `sys.syslanguages`.

Para solucionar este problema, tendrías que crear una función que regrese el nombre del mes. En lo personal, recomiendo usar una función tipo tabla en linea ya que no sufren de problemas de rendimiento como el resto de las funciones.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.NomDelMes(
    @data   datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
SELECT CASE MONTH(@data)
            WHEN 01 THEN 'gener'
            WHEN 02 THEN 'febrer'
            WHEN 03 THEN 'març'
            WHEN 04 THEN 'abril'
            WHEN 05 THEN 'maig'
            WHEN 06 THEN 'juny'
            WHEN 07 THEN 'juliol'
            WHEN 08 THEN 'agost'
            WHEN 09 THEN 'setembre'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'octubre'
            WHEN 11 THEN 'novembre'
            WHEN 12 THEN 'desembre' END AS Mes
GO
```

Una vez que tienes la función, la forma de llamarla cambia un poco respecto a las funciones escalares. Aquí dejo un ejemplo.

```
SELECT t.*,
    nm.Mes
FROM Tabla t
CROSS APPLY dbo.NomDelMes( t.fecha) nm
```

Comment: Perfecto ! Me sirvió esta solución

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando sp_configure para definir un lenguaje por default

ejemplo:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 5 ;
```

donde 5 = Spanish

[Configure the default language Server Configuration Option](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-default-language-server-configuration-option?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017#TsqlProcedure)

Comment: Pero eso no soluciona el problema porque el Catalán no se puede configurar en SQL Server.